# How infer type modification when executing function what transforms an object?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Can I somehow instruct the Typescript compiler to change the type definition as return value of a function which is called later on in a different place? I have some decorators which register some metadata about class properties and then I make transformations based on that metadata:

```
class MyClass {
  @Expose({ name: 'some_property'}) <-- the name value is explicitly provided so known at compile time
  public someProperty()
}

const result = classToPlain(/* MyClass */ { someProperty: 'some-value' })
// --> I would like to have an inferred type here as simple object with { some_property: 'some-value'}
```

```
// in classToPlain somewhere:
const propertyMetadatas.forEach(hander => {
  // transform the input object based on the metadata
  handler.transform(inputObject, outputObject) 
  // -> this assigns the original value from input to the `some_propety` value on the result
})
```

I am not familiar with any way to pass type change along the way. Is it possible somehow?

Comment: Ugh, decorators. They don't change the type of `MyClass` seen by the compiler, so it's not really true that the name value is "known at compile time" to the compiler... at least not in any way that connects it to `MyClass`.  If you care about this sort of thing I recommend you give up on decorators and fall back to calling a function (i.e., how decorators are implemented) or maybe even just adding an `expose` property to classes that work this way.

Comment: Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/rw2XYm) work for you?  It doesn't use decorators, and there are undoubtedly edge cases, but it's the general way I'd imagine proceeding if you want TypeScript to be aware of the typings.  Let me know and if it's vaguely reasonable I'll write it up as an anwer.  Otherwise the answer is probably just "no you can't do this" with a pointer to [microsoft/TypeScript#4881](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4881) and specifically [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4881#issuecomment-450938639)